# Pianobar - error protocol incompatible

Tags: 11.10, protocol, pianobar

This error pops up when I try to run "pianobar" from my Ubuntu 11.10 terminal

```
(i) Login... Error: Protocol incompatible. Please upgrade libpiano.
```

I have upgraded libpiano but it still doesn't work.

What gives?

Comment: This seems to have sorted itself out. Perhaps there was a recent update made to Ubuntu 11.10...

Answer (score 2):

*(This problem was solved by the OP by updating:)*

> This seems to have sorted itself out. Perhaps there was a recent update made to Ubuntu 11.10